# Parametric or non parametric mixed effect models for very small sample size in ecological/soil data?

Tags: nonparametric, glmm, environmental-data, parametric

I am running an ecological/environmental experiment in a salt marsh with 5 experimental treatments and 3 replicate soil samples taken from each treatment. I have been taking measurements from these treatments across three seasons, giving me three timepoints for my experimental variables. I want to run a mixed effect model with my target experimental variable (gaseous nitrogen removal from each treatment) and season (spring, summer, fall) as fixed effects and replication as a random effect. Given that I have so few replicates, I would like to opt for a non-parametric test because I think a sample size of 3 is too small to adequately evaluate the assumptions for parametric tests. Am I on the right track with this thinking? If so, what test is recommended for non-parametric mixed effect models?

Comment: Why do you want to declare the replicates as random effects? If I understand correctly, each combination of treatment and season (5 * 3 = 15 combinations) will be a cluster with three measurements. It may be easier to average the three replicates.

Comment: @dipetkov the decision to declare replicates as random effect is based off of several papers I have read that perform the same kind of experimental design and experimental variables using this type of random effect assignment. I guess they are accounting for the high variability between replicates that is commonly seen in salt marsh samples.

Comment: It makes sense to utilize methods that are commonly used in your field. Then why look at non-parametric methods? Another option -- somewhat in the opposite direction of what you are considering -- is to do Bayesian analysis. This would allow you to incorporate knowledge from related studies via the priors. Using (moderately) informative priors could work well with a small dataset.

Comment: @dipetkov I want to go the non-parametric route because my sample size is smaller than those other papers. Granted, those papers still have samples sizes of 5-10 which isn't huge but it grants more confidence for testing their normality assumptions. One of my thesis committee members also recommended that I look into nonparametric tests for GLMM.